# Why email parameter in query annotation of my repository is not working?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My repository has a method that find users by email, I use query annotation and some parameters but it's not working, it return ?. This is detail:
Repository class:

```
package com.baothien.server.repository;

import com.baothien.server.model.Users;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.email = :email")
    List<Users> findUserByEmail(@Param("email") String email);
}
```

A method to get userlist in my service class:

```
public List<Users> getAllByEmail(String email) {
    return userRepository.findUserByEmail(email);
}
```

When i test, it return:

> Hibernate:
> select
> u1_0.id,
> u1_0.email,
> u1_0.full_name,
> u1_0.password,
> u1_0.role_num
> from
> users u1_0
> where
> u1_0.email=?

In where condition, u1_0.email=?, why it return ? and it's not working. I need the solution, thank you very much for reading and solving!

I read a lot in JPA documentation, follow it but still not working.

Comment: WOrks as it should. Query parameters in JDBC show up as `?` and they will be replaced by the driver or database (depending on the DB you are using) with the actual value.

Comment: Could you share with Users model class please, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Show-up wild card is correct behavior.

It is called a prepared statement. The driver will prepare it and pass the parameter, the parameter will be hidden for log.
Let's think if you insert a password field and the hash password shows up in the log. It is terrible.

If you still want to show it, for a real reason. Add the following line to the config.

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

Comment: prepared statements are more used as a defence against SQL injection and performance reason the parsed statements can get cached on the server side.